# Multiple Awaitable in one Asynch method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an async method **Save** which internally calls **CompleteTaskAsync** method as below:

```
           public async void Save()
            {
                await CompleteTaskAsync();

                MessageBox.Show("TaskCompleted");
            }

            private async Task CompleteTaskAsync()
            {
                int someResult = await GetResultAsync();//Does some calculation which take few seconds.

                await FinalSave(someResult);//Note: This method also interact UI internally
            }
```

CompleteTaskAsync calls two methods in which second method is using output of the first.

In current case MessageBox is coming just after calling first method(GetResultAsync), without calling second method(FinalSave).

I want both await method to be executed before showing the message. Is there any way to execute both await methods before returning to its calling method.

Answer (score 2):

`MessageBox.Show("TaskCompleted");` will not be called until the `Task` instance returned by `CompleteTaskAsync` is completed, which will in turn not be completed until both of the `Task` instances returned by `GetResultAsync` and `FinalSave` are completed.

Your use of `async`/`await` and the behavior you are requesting are consistent.  Can you give any more information?  I believe your problem does not lie in the code shown.